# model form inline validation and changing the choices

Tags: python, django

Im new to Django/Python so excuse the stupidity. I have a model form with a couple of choice fields. There are validations on the fields when I perform a submit. This is all working well. Now I want to change the validation to inline validate the selection of the first choice field and then change the second choice field dependant on what was selected for the first choice field. Please excuse the following bad example, but you will get the idea

Example
models.py:

```
fruit_list = (
    ('apple','Apple'),
    ('berries','Berries),
)

apple_color = (
    ('red', 'Red'),
    ('green', 'Green'),
)

berries_color = (
    ('red','Red'),
    ('blue', 'Blue'),
)

class fruit(models.Model):
    fruit = models.Charfield(max_lenght=7, choices=fruit_list)
    color = models.Charfield(max_lenght=5, choices=?????) ##Here Im looking for the answer on how to switches between the two options. Maybe just a normal form
    def __unicode__(self): ##python 3 use __str__
        return str(self.fruit)
```

form:

```
class fruit(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = request
        fields = [ 'fruit', 'color' ]
```

Also so my validation is on the HTML post as per my view below. But how do I do inline validation, not on my post

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = fruit(request.POST, request.FILES)
        title = "Request Form"
        context = {
                "title": title,
                "form": form,
        }

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False) 
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = fruit()
        title = "Request Form"
        context = {
                "title": title,
                "form": form,
        }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

Comment: Classes in Python should start with a capital. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id36

Comment: you're not saving anything there with save(commit=False). I don't know if thats the goal

Comment: Hi Dietbacon, sorry I have ommitted the instance.save()

Comment: I want to do two things. 1) Validate a field before I submit instead of only validating a field after I submit

Comment: 2) Change the models.py color choices dependant on the selection of fruit

Answer (score 0):

*models.py*

```
fruit_list = (
    ('apple','Apple'),
    ('berries','Berries),
)

apple_color = (
   ('red', 'Red'),
   ('green', 'Green'),
)

berries_color = (
    ('red','Red'),
    ('blue', 'Blue'),
)

class Fruit(models.Model):
    fruit = models.Charfield(max_lenght=7, choices=fruit_list)
    color = models.Charfield(max_lenght=5)  # Not a choice field

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.fruit)
```

*forms.py*

```
class FruitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Fruit
        fields = [ 'fruit', 'color' ]

    def clean_color(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        fruit = data['fruit']
        color = data['color']

        if fruit == 'apple' and color not in dict(apple_color).keys():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid selection')
        if fruit == 'berries' and color not in dict(berries_color).keys():            
            raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid selection')
        return data
```

Once you select items from `fruit_list`, trigger one ajax call to another view and pass selected item ('apple' or 'berries').

```
import simplejson
from django.http import HttpResponse

def fruit_color_list(request):
    fruit = request.GET.get('fruit')
    if fruit == apple:
        fruit_list = apple_color
    else:
        fruit_list = berries_color

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(fruit_list))
```

Populate this response in your fruit color list using javascript. Rest of the flow is same.

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ....
        ....
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save() 
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        ....
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```